# MVC and javascript new approach; Q: May I have problems in future with this approach?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ria

I will explain my idea behind this:
I use python for google app engine + js + css

the main project will be stored under the src folder like this:
\src
  \app <--- here goes all the python app for gae
  \javascript <--- my non-packed javascript files
  \static_files <--- static files for gae

now the javascript dir looks like this

\javascript
  \frameworks <--- maybe jQuery && jQueryUI
  \models <--- js files
  \controllers <--- js files
  \views <--- HTML files!
  app.js <--- the main app for js
  compile.py <--- this is the file I will talk more

About compile.py:
This file will have 2 methods one for the min and other for the development javascript file;
When is run will do:

1. Join all the files with "js" extension;
2. The app.js contains a variable named "views" and is an object, like a hash; Then the compiler copy the contents of each file with "html" extension located in the "/javascript/views/" dir using this rule;
   example: if we have a view like this "/views/login.html" then the "views" js var will have a property named "login"; views['login'] = '...content...';
   example2: "/views/admin/sexyBitcy.html" then view['admin.sexyBitcy'] = '...content...' or whatever exists in that html file..;
3. Then this big file will be saved into the "/src/static_files/core.js"; if is minified will be saved as "/src/static_files/core.min.js";

The javascript will use dependenccy injection, or sort of it. (:

I will explain how it will work then:

1. the index.html that is loaded when you come into the site loads the core.js and the jquery.js;
2. the core.js will create the layout of the page, as SEO is not important for the most of the pages;
3. the core.js uses the controllers-models-views to create the layout of course; the html for the layout is inside the var "views"; will be a heavy variable of course!
4. Some code:

   `mvcInjector = new MVCInjector;`
   `mvcInjector.mapView(views['login'], 'login', LoginController);`
   `parent = $('#jscontent');`

jquery
    view = mvcInjector.instanceView('login', parent); // <--- this will create the contents of the views['login'] in the parent node "parent = $('#jscontent');" then will instance the LoginController that will map the "SkinParts" (like in FLEX if you know); what does it mean map the "SkinParts"? - when the user will click on a button an handler for that action is defined in the controller; ex.:

// LoginController

```
this.init = function(){
  // map skin parts
  this.mapSkinPart('email', 'input[name]="email"');
  this.mapSkinPart('submit', 'input[name]="submit"');

  // link skin parts to handlers
  this.getSkinPart('submit').click = this.login;
}

// handlers
this.login = function(event){
  // connect to the db
  // some problems here the get the value as the "this" keyword references to the this of the controller class, I will work it around soon
  alert('open window button1' + this.getSkinPart('email').value());
}
```

**If something is not clear just say something, I will be happy to explain;
So the question remains: is this scalable, manageable and fast enough for a big RIA application build with javascript+jquery and maybe with jqueryUI?**

**Thanks ;)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like your idea quit a bit.

I would think about loading html pages by ajax, if they are big and there are many of them...

Have a look on [angular](http://www.angularjs.org/Main_Page) project, I hope, it could help you a lot. It's a kind of JS framework, designed to work together with jQuery. Well suitable for test driven development.
It uses html as templates, you can simply create your own controllers, use dependency injector, etc... Feel free to ask any question on [mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/angular).

Then, I must recommend [JsTestDriver](http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/) - really cool test runner for JS (so you can easily run unit tests in many browsers, during development - let's say after save...)

Comment: well my pages are not properly pages, they are window contents, just the template then is populated via js, and are used over and over again. They will use to be small so only the core components will be loaded by default, the others will be loaded by ajax

Nice the angular, but I have to spend some time understanding namespaces in html and binding...